# How to send Notification Msg for login client(Spring Mvc Web Applicaiton)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, notifications

How to inform to user for update data on server that why i want to send notification for LogIn client in web application (Spring MVC)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to used the web socket programming to notified user from server to client user. You can get help from this link for more detail:

https://github.com/iotasol/AngularJs-and-Websocket-with-java-spring

Comment: suppose 10 user login my application i want to inform them using notification that is possible

Comment: Yes, you can able to notified the N number of user which will be listener to topic. For example : https://github.com/iotasol/AngularJs-and-Websocket-with-java-spring/blob/master/src/main/java/com/demo/controller/login/GreetingController.java . Here you are sending message to topic/greetings. Now all user which will be listener to topic/greetings will get the message.

Comment: How to test this example in my web application

Comment: You have to review code i.e in angular part also have listener for server event

Comment: Can u give me some other example ?